# How to print gerrit comments of latest patchset?

Tags: gerrit

This prints the comments from all the patchset, is there a way to print comments only from latest patchset?

```
ssh -x -p $PORT $SERVER gerrit query --current-patch-set change:1234 --comments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command already shows only the comments from the latest patchset. I think you're talking about the comments in the change and not in the others patchsets (for example: "Uploaded patch set 1", "Patch Set 2: Code-Review+2", etc). There isn't a way to not show these comments.

See more info in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html).